# Value of a function over permutations of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, physics, simulation, permutation

I want to do the sum (in Ising lattice gauge theory)

```
n = 3;
energy[sx_,sy_] := Sum[sx[[i, j]] sy[[i, j]] sx[[i + 1, j]] sy[[i, j + 1]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
sx = Tuples[{-1,1}, {n+1,n}];
sy = Tuples[{-1,1}, {n,n+1}];
```

I want the values of this function over all possible permutations of `sx` and `sy` but I am unable to find a way to do so. Basically this is a variant of the usual Ising model but this time the spins placed on the bonds instead of the nodes. Spins still take values $\pm 1$ but the Hamiltonian is now the product of spins on a 'square'. I am trying to calculate the partition function of this model and hence this sum arose. I divided the spins into ones along the $x$ axis and others along the $y$ axis and hence am using two lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: as pointed out in the comment the definitions of `sx` and `sy` are wrong. `sx` is the name of the matrix of horizontal bonds and `sy` is the matrix of vertical bonds.

Comment: Your sx is a 4096x4 grid containing entries of 3 numbers. Your sy is a 4096x3 grid containing entries of 4 numbers. You can't multiply them.

Comment: @flinty thanks for pointing that out. That's what my mistake and confusion is actually. My sx is an (n+1) x n matrix (horizontal bonds in an n x n grid) and sy is an n x (n+1) matrix (vertical bonds in an n x n grid). I want to sum over these matrix elements taking the values {-1,1}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the multiplications more efficiently without needing `Sum`.

```
Remove["Global`*"];
energy[sx_, sy_] := 
 Total[Most[sx]*sy[[All, ;; -2]]*Rest[sx]*sy[[All, 2 ;;]], 2]

SeedRandom[123];
sx = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {4, 3}];
sy = RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {3, 4}];
energy[sx, sy]
(* 5 *)
```

Summing over all permutations is easy, but I wouldn't make `n` much bigger due to memory constraints:

```
Remove["Global`*"];

energy[sx_, sy_] := 
 Total[Most[sx]*sy[[All, ;; -2]]*Rest[sx]*sy[[All, 2 ;;]], 2]
n = 3;
sxPerms = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n*(n + 1)];
syPerms = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n*(n + 1)];
result = Table[
   energy[ArrayReshape[sx, {n + 1, n}], ArrayReshape[sy, {n, n + 1}]]
   , {sx, sxPerms}, {sy, syPerms}];
MatrixPlot[result]
```

[image]

This image looks cool, but it's not very meaningful. The row/col indices correspond to permutations.

Instead we can compute the grid products and preserve them, then sum later to add all possible grids together. The result is a zero matrix:

```
energy[sx_, sy_] := 
 Most[sx]*sy[[All, ;; -2]]*Rest[sx]*sy[[All, 2 ;;]]
n = 3;
sxPerms = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n*(n + 1)];
syPerms = Tuples[{-1, 1}, n*(n + 1)];
result = 
  Sum[energy[ArrayReshape[sx, {n + 1, n}], 
    ArrayReshape[sy, {n, n + 1}]], {sx, sxPerms}, {sy, syPerms}];

(* {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}} *)
```

---

Also, you can avoid needing to store the tuples by generating them based off an index. This is slower, but uses less memory:

```
Remove["Global`*"];

energy[sx_, sy_] := 
 Total[Most[sx]*sy[[All, ;; -2]]*Rest[sx]*sy[[All, 2 ;;]], 2]
generateMatrix[i_, dim_] := With[{d = Times @@ dim},
  ArrayReshape[
   2 IntegerDigits[i, 2, IntegerLength[2^d - 1, 2]] - 1
   , dim]]

n = 3;
result = 
  ParallelTable[
   energy[generateMatrix[ix, {n + 1, n}], 
    generateMatrix[iy, {n, n + 1}]]
   , {ix, 0, 2^(n*(n + 1)) - 1}, {iy, 0, 2^(n*(n + 1)) - 1}];
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. I need the value of energies for all such permutations of the matrices sx, sy (starting with all elements = 1 to all elements = -1). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @QFTheorist added. The total energy: `Total[result, 2]` gives 0.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have learnt a lot from this single answer of yours. I am forever grateful. Can you recommend me some resources to learn Mathematica better? I am fairly new to the language. Once again I thank you so much. (I don't need the sum of energy, but the partition function, but I can move ahead from here on my own.)

Comment: @QFTheorist https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/259/72682

Comment: Thanks. BTW should both sxPerms and syPerms be of the size n*(n+1) instead of n*n+1?

Comment: @QFTheorist Good catch. Fixed now. It's a bit slower due to the increased number of tuples.